# Why does my accuracy hit a threshold that it cannot overcome?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, data-science

I have a ML project I'm working on where I am trying to predict the winner of a League of Legends game. I am training on 50,000 games right now (I have 20 million data points total in storage), and my model is getting very poor results.

My data is in a csv file with the first 5 columns being numbers representing the champion IDs of one team, the next 5 columns being numbers representing the champion IDs of the other team, and the 11th column being a 1 or 0 (1 for first team victory, 0 for first team loss)

For example, 1 row looks like:
[image: 1 datapoint]

and it is loaded in using numpy:

`dataset = loadtxt('/content/drive/MyDrive/Data/dataset.csv', delimiter=',')`

Can anyone help out please? I am not very familiar with Keras so I'm not sure if my model itself needs fixing or if there might be an issue with my data.

The model:

```
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and here are my accuracy/loss graphs:

[image: Accuracy]

[image: Loss]

Comment: Could you please describe/ show all of the features you are using?

Comment: Also that network seems too shallow for 50K data points.

Comment: @R.Schaefer I am only using the csv file mentioned above, of which I just attached a screenshot of what 1 row looks like, and how it is loaded in. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Frightera Could you expand on the best way to fix this problem? Do I simply just add more layers or is there an intuition on how best to do it. Thank you in advance

Comment: Scale your data firstly. And after try to add some more layers. You need to experiment the layers, there is no straight forward answer for it.

Comment: @Frightera What do you mean by "Scale your data"? Sorry for not understanding. 

In league of legends each champion has a unique champion ID which I am using for the data input

Answer (score 1):

Your champion IDs are nominal categorical variables and you have to convert them so that each has their own dimension. If you load the csv into Pandas then you would change the type to categorical for columns 0 to 9 and keep the 11th as it is. Then call `pd.get_dummies(df)` on your dataframe. SKLearn also has a function for converting to one-hot. There is a multitude of ways to do it in NumPy.

The champion IDs seem to be integers though so if you converted them to integers then you could pass each of those columns to an embedding layer and vectorize directly in your model. Much simpler. However, you will have to use the Functional API instead of Sequential for that.

**Edit** (this is without checking if it works and assuming 140 classes in IDs):

```py
dataset = dataset.astype('int32')
data = [dataset[:, i] for i in range(dataset.shape[1])]
inputs = [Input((1,), dtype=tf.int32) for _ in data[:-1]]
embs = [Embedding(140, 5)(inp) for inp in inputs]
concat = Concatenate()(embs)
x = Dense(12, activation='relu')(concat)
x = Dense(8, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data[:-1], data[-1])
```

Approximately anyway. I don't have any data and you haven't supplied any in the question that I could use. In the long run you'll probably want to look at convolutions so that the order of the champions on each team doesn't matter but see if you can't get this running first. Hyperparameters to optimize first are 5, 12, and 8 as well as the number of layers. And the learning rate.

Comment: If you one-hot encode your data you will get hundreds or thousands of dimensions in your input data. You will probably not be able to load all of your data then. One more reason embedding is a better solution. And you can have a lower output dimension on the embedding layer than if you one-hot encoded everything which will reduce the number of parameters in the model and reduce overfitting.

Comment: Thank you! Can you point me in the starting direction for embedding and vectorizing directly in my model?

I found this online: https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/
but I'm not sure what parameters to use

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment. If your input isn't ready for input into the embedding layer then there's https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/StringLookup for strings and an equivalent for re-mapper for integers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, based on the data used, no matter which model, will probably ever deliver good results. One reason is that there are a lot of possible combinations available (573658984353378; ~140 champions, and 10 champions are picked each round). Furthermore I don't think that only the chosen champions are enough for good prediction results. Imagine one pro team is playing with untypical champions in a weird setup, but they still probably win vs another team with very strong champions. In addition to the above statement, the data might be heavily biased, under- / oversampling might be appropriated to generate a dataset which contains 50% of wins and 50% of loses.

Your model has to derive and is assuming too much variables which it can't observe. To improve your results, additional data such as the following might lead to better results:

- Which champions belongs to which team? How many teams are there?
- Mapping of champs to roles; imagine soraka is jungling, rammus covers  mid lane, etc.
- Metrics / skills of the players and their usual roles and played champions
- Mapping of champs to runes, spells and ability order
- Determine type of champion skills (damage, support, exhaust, ...)
- Damage type / defense type of champions
- Information about bought items of each champ; order matters, too
- Control about map / vision / dragons / ...
- Stats about farmed gold, killed champions, dealt damage, etc.
- Gold distribution of team and players
- etc..